# Why javafx.geometry.Point2D doesn't have setLocation(x,y) method

Tags: javafx

In JavaFX the javafx.geometry.Point2D is missing a core method setLocation(x,y)
I wonder why this object made immutable?

For performance one would like to minimize the number of new instances created and therefore ability to reuse the Point2D would be nice.

Comment: The comment on [this RFE](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8153377) says it was intentionally made immutable. I'm guessing it should be possible to find the discussion by digging deep enough in the OpenJFX mailing list archives...

Comment: I had the same question also . So i made one custom `Point2D` class ;)

Comment: `Point2D.ZERO.setLocation(1, 1)`

Comment: @fabian dunno what version of fx are you running but my Point2D.ZERO doesnt have setLocation()

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS I did that too but I its ugly since the x,y are private so I had to use reflection

Comment: @omid the problem with your suggestion is that add() creates new instance  too

Comment: oh, right! my bad. you don't need new instances :)

Comment: @Deian exactly, but I'm pretty sure you can guess what kind of problems could arise, if this was possible to mutate a `static final` field called `ZERO` this way...

Answer (score -1):

IMHO the whole design of JavaFx 1.x is broken not introduced this. As alternative I recommend the much more well designed Scene Shapes API of JavaFx 2.0 with full accessibility to all properties. They omit a point there but a Rectangle could be easily used as replacement for instance.